# How can we add groups of rows to Google Sheets depending on input rows on another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Looking for help with Google Sheets.

We are looking to have a sheet that creates summary information based on the input of data in another sheet.

[Let's say we have a list of people like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzS7x.jpg)

[In another sheet within the same document, we could like output like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEfDa.jpg)

As the original data sheet grows, we may get more people. The input would grow and look like this:

```
Room ID First Name  Last Name   Full Name       State   Zip    Room Leader
1       Brian       Smith       Brian Smith     NY      10011   
1       Lazy        Fox         Lazy Fox        VA      22209  Yes
2       Lauren      Appleby     Lauren Appleby  CA      94063  Yes
3       Aaron       Johnson     Aaron Johnson   IL      60603  Yes
3       Adam        Johnson     Adam Johnson    IL      60001
```

When that happens, we want the output to change to reflect that. It could look like this.

```
Room Number 1          State    VA
Name        Lazy Fox        
Room Number 2          State    CA
Name        Lauren Appleby      
Room Number 3          State    IL
Name    Aaron Johnson
```

Sorry for the random cut and pastes, I guess I don't have enough rep to add everything. Hopefully it gets the point across though.

Is this something that's possible? Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just to let you know some of us will not go to links that aren't Google Links and I'm one of them.  How did you pick the three out the six.   Are they room leaders?

Comment: Yeah, sorry when I try to embed images, StackOverflow only lets me embed the links. Not enough reputation I guess. Also yes, it's by Room Leader.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your summary as a modeless dialog.  I used your headers as the summary field names. And I assumed you wanted rows where there was a Yes in the Room Leader column.

```
function dispSummary()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('RoomInfo');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var s='<style>.ttl{color:blue;}</style>';
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][6]=='Yes')
    {
      s+='<br />' + '<span class="ttl">' + rngA[0][0] + '</span>' + ' = ' + rngA[i][0] + '    ' + '<span class="ttl">' + rngA[0][4] + '</span>' + ' = ' + rngA[i][4] + '    ' + '<span class="ttl">' + rngA[0][3] + '</span>' + ' = ' + rngA[i][3];
    }
  }
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(600).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Values Found')
}
```

In case you would like them lined up better, here's the same thing in table.

```
function dispSummary()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('RoomInfo');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var s='<style>.ttl{color:blue;}</style><table>';
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][6]=='Yes')
    {
      s+='<tr><td>' + '<span class="ttl">' + rngA[0][0] + '</span>' + ' = ' + rngA[i][0] + '</td><td>' + '<span class="ttl">' + rngA[0][4] + '</span>' + ' = ' + rngA[i][4] + '</td><td>' + '<span class="ttl">' + rngA[0][3] + '</span>' + ' = ' + rngA[i][3] + '</td></tr>';
    }
  }
  s+='</table>';
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(600).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Values Found')
}
```

Or perhaps you would like to put the summary on another sheet here's a way to do that.

```
function dispSummary()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('RoomInfo');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var sumsht = ss.getSheetByName('Summary')
  var sumA = [];
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][6]=='Yes')
    {
      sumA.push( [rngA[0][0],rngA[i][0],rngA[0][4],rngA[i][4],rngA[0][3],rngA[i][3]]); 
    }
  }
  var sumrng = sumsht.getRange(1,1,sumA.length,sumA[0].length);
  sumrng.setValues(sumA);
}
```

And this approach puts your desired header columns in the top row and has only data in the  rest of the output sheet.

```
function dispSummary()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('RoomInfo');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var sumsht = ss.getSheetByName('Summary')
  var sumA = [];
  sumA.push( [rngA[0][0],rngA[0][4],rngA[0][3]]);
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][6]=='Yes')
    {
      sumA.push( [rngA[i][0],rngA[i][4],rngA[i][3]]); 
    }
  }
  var sumrng = sumsht.getRange(1,1,sumA.length,sumA[0].length);
  sumrng.setValues(sumA);
  sumsht.activate();//you could add this if you want to go to the summary sheet immediately after the script completes.
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that does work, but might wanted to clarify more (or maybe I just don't know how to execute it properly).

So I tried that in the script editor, and that does work when I hit the execute button.

What I was more looking for though was it to work in the actual sheet, because it's something that will be running from the mobile device. Is this something that would do that? Or would I have to have a different approach?

Comment: I added the output sheet solution just now.  I was just giving you some options.  But you can see that the code is pretty much the same thing.  The only thing that you have to be careful about is making sure that the output value array and the output domain size have to be the same size. And you can do that by setting the output range to the dimensions of the output value array.

Comment: @BrianSuk I added several different ways to display your data. Two ways using dialogs and 2 ways using tables.  Hopefully, one of those is close to what you need.

Comment: Ah awesome, your suggestions on inserting into other tables might be the winner, will give that a shot!

One more question on that though, is there a way to include formatting as well? When functions replace the data it seems that it resets the formatting all the time and there's lot of colors and text formatting going on. Is there an Apps Script function (or set of functions) that might help?

Comment: Yes you can set formatting via apps scripting.  Check out the [range page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) here.  I have to admit that it's not something I usually care about so I don't mess around with it much.  If the data is readable and chartable then that's good enough for me.  But you might like to ask that as another question and get some others involved in the solution.

Comment: Thanks a ton, will give his a shot and report back!